# How to generate a positive square wave in matlab, whose cumulative sum should be equal to a given value?

Tags: matlab, frequency

I have a cumulative rain, R = 100 mm for t = 10 days. I want to distribute the R over t through square wave so that the cumulative of the square wave is equal to R. In fact, I want to generate different scenario by changing the frequency and duration of rainfall, however, for all cases, the cumulative R should be same.
Please suggest.
Regards,
Imran

Comment: I just tried with square command with matlab. But, couldn't find any clue to make the cumulative equal to the given one. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it on paper first - this is arguably a maths question really.

The trick is to be clear about all your definitions (this is also why you're getting downvotes - those same definitions are required for people to give you detailed help).

Start with the definition of a square wave that fits your requirements (i.e. the two levels it occupies). Define your cumulative and determine how to compute it. You should then be able to write an expression which relates the duty cycle of the square wave (choose a letter for this parameter) and the total time period (your t) to the cumulative (your R). Then you can invert the relationship such that, for a given cumulative R and time t you can recover the required duty cycle.

When you've done this you'll probably find it a great deal easier to implement in matlab.

If you have trouble with any of these stages then ask a new question about it, remembering to include what you've tried so far.